# Simple application with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to build my first facebook app using php sdk.
In order to get user's name, I tried this code

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_friendList = $facebook->api('/me/friends?access_token='.$access_token);
     $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Utente <?php  echo $user_profile['name']; ?>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
  </body>
</html>
```

But the only thing I get as html output is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 Utente   
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/0/picture">
  </body>
</html>
```

Using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` I'm getting

> Notice: Undefined variable: user_profile in
>   /membri/angeange/fb/test.php on line 27 ( `Utente <?php  echo $user_profile['name']; ?>` )

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $user is false then $user_profile is not set

Comment: Yeah, but I can't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this SDK are you using is deprecated.

Go to developers.facebook.com and check the new version available.

Comment: Yeah, actually the sdk was up to date, but I was using a version of php which didn't support it and a code designed for a previous version.
I tried to use the latest version of php with an updated code and it works.